# AS3 numerical array sorting?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, sorting

```
var dataArray:Array = [ 5, 6, 3, 8, 10, 11, 32, 2 ];
var dataObjectArray:Array [ { "uid": 5 }, { "uid": 6 .... Similar to above ... } ];
```

I have the above 2 arrays in AS3. and i wish to sort them numerically (1 ~ X) in order [Skipping those that does not exist]. What is the best and most efficent way to do so for dataArray / dataObjectArray.

You may solve 1, or both =)

Comment: You can check here: http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=245 for a compassion between sorting algorithms, in AS3, for arrays

Comment: I imagine you already know this, but just in case, if you decide to work with object-arrays / associative arrays (or more accurately 'objects') these can be sorted in AS3 but will be traversed in a random order.

Comment: @tomfumb do u mean the order is random in a for( name:String in obj ) calls?

Comment: @pico.creator yes, and for a long time it confused the hell out of me as AS3 is happy to let you go on sorting those and pulling your hair out accusing the language of not working properly.

Comment: @tomfumb : haha, the hair pulling out part seems to be a common occurring event for me in flex though >.<

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
dataArray.sort(  Array.NUMERIC );
dataObjectArray.sortOn( ["uid"], [Array.NUMERIC]);
```

Comment: Haha, just did: posted it too 2mins before you. Took some time to find something so convienent though

Comment: @pico.creator: SO should somehow let you know that someone has posted an answer while you are still writing yours ;) tnxs anyways for the mark.

Comment: It was certainly a surprise =] : Giving myself the answer is just ~wierd~ anyway, haha

Answer (score 6):

Surprisingly, as3 has in-built functions for this.

```
 dataArray.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
 dataObjectArray.sortOn("uid", Array.NUMERIC);
```

This would elegantly give the effect desired: Ascending order is by default. The array documentation covers additional details, such as descending order/etc... Lol sortOn even sorts nested objects / array if the field values are provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataArray.sort();
```

Will automatically recognize if you're sorting numbers or strings and sort the array.
But then I did something stupid. My array contains numbers as strings and then the sorting didn't work well when there were different number of digits when they're strings.
So the winning solution is the full great answer:

```
dataArray.sort(  Array.NUMERIC );
dataObjectArray.sortOn( ["uid"], [Array.NUMERIC]);
```

If you want a reversed order (descending and not ascending order), then after sorting call:

```
dataArray.reverse();
```

Cheers!